# Alter table in mysql is showing (Runnig message)

Tags: mysql

I am tring to alter the table with below statement.In the below query which one give me a solution to alter my table user_master.if not please give me a idea to alter my table.

Thanks all

```
ALTER TABLE user_master
MODIFY   Password  VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE user_master
CHANGE COLUMN Password Password VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL;

 ALTER TABLE user_master MODIFY Password VARCHAR(200)
```

but MySQL work bench it's showing message [image]

Here MySQL problem or my query problem? what I need to solve this?

Comment: I don't think any problem with the query

Comment: hi could any one check in your system alter column is working are not.my doubt may be  MySQL  had some problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query seems fine, please check what is running on your server by below command:

```
show full processlist;
```

Note: check if any alter command is running. Also share what is your table size.

Comment: 5 columns I had in my table (userid,password,datetime,usertype,isactive)

Comment: If you are using innodb engine then kill all alter statements and execute one fresh alter also share table size.

Comment: my table size table_rows =16,data_lenght=16384,size in MB=0.02

Comment: yes I had kill all execute fresh one it's still running

Comment: here it's showing error:Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column 'Password' at row 7

Comment: I used below command ALTER IGNORE  TABLE user_master
  CHANGE  Password Password VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL; worked for me thank you Zafar Malik